# Time Complexity best, worst and average case

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

Hi guys Can you explain to me this in simple words

1. Best-case complexity -of the algorithm is the function defined by the maximum number of    steps taken on any instance of size N
2. Worst-case complexity -of the algorithm is the function defined by the maximum number of steps taken on any instance of size N
3. Average-case complexity- of the algorithm is the function defined by the average number of steps on any instance of size N

Answer (score 1):

The worst-case is the one on which your algorithm requires the biggest number of operations. So, if you use this solution on some input data, then the worst-case complexity will give the upper bound i.e. it won't be worse than this. On the other hand, the best-case tells that your algorithm won't be better on any input data.

The average case gives you the average complexity of operations, when running on many samples of input data.